# C#, Outlook Addon, Open webpage inside outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am wondering how to open a website inside Outlook 2007 programmatically using C#?

and still retain the ToDo bar.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Option A (Outlook built-in browser):**

```
(Office.CommandBarComboBox)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars.FindControl(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlComboBox, 1740, missing, missing);
```

**Option B (customPanel (retains todobar)):**

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new TaskPanel(), "Browser", explorer);
```

Comment: Put your codes in a code block, it will improve your answer readability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I bet you can display a Windows Forms form, right? Put a WebBrowser control on that form, and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Option A from ricardojferreira's answer works good in Outlook 2007 and 2010. But it doesn't work in 2013.

Is there a convenient way to do it in 2013?

I know about WebViewURL property of MapiFolder, but to make it work nice I need to create special folder just for browsing urls.